# Detect if keyboard is running in compatibility mode app on iPhone X

Tags: ios, keyboard, iphone-x

I have built a custom keyboard extension that can be used in any app. A need has arisen for the ability to programmatically detect from within the keyboard if the app being used is running at native resolution on iPhone X, or if it's being run in compatibility mode at iPhone 8 res. The keyboard needs to adjust it's behavior slightly for these two different scenarios.

I originally speculated perhaps `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` would return the size of the compatibility window, but alas, it returns 375x812 for both scenarios. Consistently, `nativeBounds` returns 1125x2436. The `inputView` and its `superview` also are 375x812.

How can one determine if the app hosting the keyboard is running in compatibility mode on iPhone X?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone X, so I have to ask: does it really _have_ this compatibility mode feature? I see a lot of people looking for it and not finding it. On my iPhone 6s there is a Display Zoom setting under Display & Brightness that basically causes us to become an iPhone 5s. But the discussions I've found on the forums say that iPhone X doesn't have that.

Comment: @matt When you open an app on iPhone X that hasn't been optimized for iPhone X, it runs at iPhone 8 resolution centered vertically on screen with black bars at the top and bottom, just like what occurred with the transition from iPhone 4s to 5. The keyboard is restricted within that 'compatibility window' as well.

Comment: OK, then you can't detect that. Nothing changes about the resolution or size (as you have found).